# How to get more space underneath a block in beamer?

Tags: beamer, spacing

I'm creating a `beamer` presentation. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\useoutertheme{miniframes} %Titelbalken
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

%Packages
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\newenvironment{te bewijzen}[1][]
{\textbf{Te bewijzen:} #1}

\newenvironment{bewijs}[1]{
    \pushQED{\qed}
    \textbf{Bewijs:} #1}
{\popQED}

\begin{document}

\section{Deelvraag 1}

\subsection{Bewijs}
\frame{\frametitle{Bewijs}
    \begin{block}{Block}
        some text in my block
    \end{block}
    \begin{te bewijzen}
        this is what I have to prove
    \end{te bewijzen}
    \begin{bewijs}
        \begin{align*}
                               & line 1\\
            \Longrightarrow~    & line 2\\
            \Longrightarrow~    & line 3\\
            \Longrightarrow~    & line 4
        \end{align*}
\end{bewijs}
}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the block and the text underneath are a bit close together and I don't really like that. How can I get some more space between them?

Comment: Can't you add `\vspace*{10pt}` or `\bigskip` or similar after the `block`?

Comment: Hi! Would `\medskip` help? (Sorry, I don't have a good LaTeX here now, so I can't test.) You can put it directly at the beginning of `te bewijzen` definition, too. Just one note: you can try `\implies` instead of `\Longrightarrow~` ;)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but please consider to also upvote it -- upvoting must be done separate from accepting.

Comment: @tohecz: `\medskip` works perfectly and `\implies` really is an improvement. Thanks!

Comment: @lockstep: Done! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding commands like `\medskip` after each block in your presentation, add the following to your preamble:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\medskip}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\useoutertheme{miniframes} %Titelbalken
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\medskip}

%Packages
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\newenvironment{te bewijzen}[1][]
{\textbf{Te bewijzen:} #1}

\newenvironment{bewijs}[1]{
    \pushQED{\qed}
    \textbf{Bewijs:} #1}
{\popQED}

\begin{document}

\section{Deelvraag 1}

\subsection{Bewijs}
\frame{\frametitle{Bewijs}
    \begin{block}{Block}
        some text in my block
    \end{block}
    \begin{te bewijzen}
        this is what I have to prove
    \end{te bewijzen}
    \begin{bewijs}
        \begin{align*}
        & line 1\\
        \Longrightarrow~    & line 2\\
        \Longrightarrow~    & line 3\\
        \Longrightarrow~    & line 4
        \end{align*}
    \end{bewijs}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As karlkoeller mentioned, you can do this by using `\vspace` or `\bigskip`. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\useoutertheme{miniframes} %Titelbalken
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

%Packages
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\newenvironment{te bewijzen}[1][]
{\textbf{Te bewijzen:} #1}

\newenvironment{bewijs}[1]{
    \pushQED{\qed}
    \textbf{Bewijs:} #1}
{\popQED}

\begin{document}

\section{Deelvraag 1}

\subsection{Bewijs}
\frame{\frametitle{Bewijs}
    \begin{block}{Block}
        some text in my block
    \end{block}

    \bigskip

    \begin{te bewijzen}
        this is what I have to prove
    \end{te bewijzen}
    \begin{bewijs}
        \begin{align*}
                               & line 1\\
            \Longrightarrow~    & line 2\\
            \Longrightarrow~    & line 3\\
            \Longrightarrow~    & line 4
        \end{align*}
\end{bewijs}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\vspace`and `\bigskip` didn't work, but @lockstep's answer is perfect.

Comment: It does work, but you have to make sure that there is an empty line between the `\end{block}` and `\bigskip` and another empty line between `\bigskip` and `\begin{te bewijzen}`

Comment: Your absolutely right: I forgot an empty line after the `\bigskip`. It works fine now. Although I find @lockstep's solution more elegant, I'll update your answer too. Thanks!